# PayPal iframe in my site

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, paypal

I've a minor problem. 
I need to implement in my site PayPal Iframe.
Like this:
[image: Picture]

Can i do it somehow without entering **SECURETOKENID** and **MySecureToken.**
Maybe we have some solutions?
This article https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/ is good, but I can't find any answers in there how I can do it?

And the problem is, I can't pay an ongoing paypal fee, maybe you will help somehow?
Some ideas what I can make?

Comment: Why did you not use a plugin ? Check this website : http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/10-wordpress-paypal-plugins-for-easily-accepting-payments/

Comment: because the task of my boss was : made this iframe staff work. 
And I try to find the way to do this.

Comment: Ok, but without a secure token, I think it's impossible. Have a look at this documentation : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/gs_ppa_hosted_pages/

Comment: and to create a secure token I need to have a Paypal Pro account? Or no?

Comment: No just a personnal Paypal account with the brick "developper" activated: https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: sorry for innoying, but maybe you could help me, I can't find any instructions to get my security token.
If you have some link for explanation, it would be great.

Comment: No problem :) all your information needed are here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_credentials/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can launch payflowlink

option 1 - By posting all parameters to Payflowlink (which is not secure )
Option 2 - By using secure token. (For this you will be calling pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com to generate securetoken first ) and then you will launch payflowlink with Secure Token - This is recommended way.

If you don't want to use secure token, then go to manager.paypal.com with your merchant account credentials, then go to administration -> setup and then disable Secure token at the very end of the page.

Hope this helps.